# I don't understand the how prime numbers are calculated and modPow function is working in the following code

Tags: c++, number-theory

A Magic Fraction for N is one that has the following properties:

```
It is a proper fraction (The value is < 1)
It cannot be reduced further (The GCD of the numerator and the denominator is 1)
The product of the numerator and the denominator is factorial of N. i.e. if a/b is the fraction, then a*b = N!
```

Examples of Magic Fractions are:

1/2 [ gcd(1,2) = 1 and 1*2=2! ]

2/3 [ gcd(2,3) = 1 and 2*3=3! ]

3/8 [ gcd(3,8) = 1 and 3*8=4! ]

2/12 for example, is not a magic fraction, as even though 2*12=4!, gcd(2,12) != 1

And Magic fractions for number 3 are: 2/3 and 1/6 (since both of them satisfy the above criteria, are of the form a/b where a*b = 3!)

Now given a number N, you need to print the total number of magic fractions that exist, for all numbers between 1 and N (include magic fractions for N, too).

Can anybody tell me what is modPow function doing?

Refer the [link](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/magic-fractions/description/) to see the question, that will give an idea why this code.

```cpp
using namespace std;
#define ll long long int
#define S(n) scanf("%lld", &n)
ll MOD = 1e18 + 7;

ll modPow(ll a, ll b)
{
    ll res = 1;
    a %= MOD;
    for (; b; b >>= 1) {
        if (b & 1)
            res = res * a % MOD;
        a = a * a % MOD;
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    ll i, j;
    ll va = 1;
    ll sum = 0;
    ll prime[1000] = { 0 };
    for (i = 2; i <= 500; i++) {
        if (prime[i] == 0)
            for (j = 2 * i; j <= 500; j += i)
                prime[j] = 1;
    }
    ll val[600] = { 0 };
    val[1] = 0;
    val[2] = 1;
    ll co = 0;
    for (i = 3; i <= 500; i++) {
        if (prime[i] == 0) {
            co++;
        }
        ll t1 = modPow(2, co);
        val[i] = t1 + val[i - 1];
        val[i] %= MOD;
        //  cout << i << " " << val[i] << "\n";
    }
    ll n;
    S(n);
    cout << val[n] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: `ll res=1;a%=MOD;for(;b;b>>=1){if(b&1)res=res*a%MOD;a=a*a%MOD;` I'm sorry but this is unreadable.

Comment: @RichardCritten I have removed the #defines. please help.

Comment: Here you you can find explanation how [a ^ b % c is calculated](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modular-exponentiation-power-in-modular-arithmetic/) in fast way.

Comment: You probably should represent MOD as `static long long MOD = 1'000'000'000'000'000'007LL;` instead of using a janky double and addition.  (The double is janky because 1e18 + 7 exceeds 9,007,199,254,740,992 so cannot be represented with fidelity.)